# Android INSTALL_REFERRER no Google Play Broadcast

Tags: broadcast, referrer

I'm trying to implement a referral feature for the app I'm building.
I've spent 5 days on this and still can't make it work with Google Play installation.

I've followed the developer guide for v3: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#google-play-testing
Implemented a Broadcast receiver that is working just fine when I'm broadcasting com.android.vending the fake Intent with ADB:
Broadcast receiver fires, everything happens as I expect it to.

When I deploy my APK to Google Play as Alpha - I don't receive the intent from Google Play.
My sequence is as follows:
Uninstall the app. 
Tap the generated URL with campaign parameters on the device.
Google Play opens. I tap Install.
My app is installed. I tap Open
App starts, but Broadcast receiver doesn't receive a thing.
I don't see com.android.vending in the Logs...

What am I doing wrong?

Device Nexus 5 (also tested on Galaxy S2, Droid X, HTC One)
Tested on Kitkat, 4.3, 4.2, 2.3.4
The URL I'm using is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inigoapp.inigoandroid&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle

Please please please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Am I the only one having this issue? :(

Comment: Everything I've read so far says that it only works with Production, not Alpha or Beta releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you need to use inside other Android apps is like the following:

```
market://details?id=com.inigoapp.inigoandroid&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle
```

Seems that the HTTP Google Play redirection does not save the referral data. Give it a try and tell us something.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. What I didn't realize is how to debug it. It must be done completely on a device. I was trying to click install on a PC and expected to get a broadcast on the phone. It didn't work for me. But if everything is done on a device it works fine.